# How to Turn Off a plot by default in the Style window of a indicator in TradingView Pine Editor?

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

I have a custom script for Multiple EMA under a single indicator. Here's my sript:

```
//@version=4

//EMA
study("Multiple EMA", overlay=true)
plot(ema(close, 9), color = color.green, linewidth=2, title='9 EMA')
plot(ema(close, 18), color = color.red, linewidth=2, title='18 EMA')
plot(ema(close, 50), color = color.red, linewidth=2, title='50 EMA')
plot(ema(close, 100), color = color.red, linewidth=2, title='100 EMA')
plot(ema(close, 200), color = color.blue, linewidth=2, title='200 EMA')
```

I want to turn off/ uncheck the "9 EMA" and "18 EMA" plots from the "Style" window by default:

[image]

How can I achieve that using the Pine Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plot()` function has an argument called `display`. You can set it to `display.none` so it will not be displayed initially.

```
plot(ema(close, 9), color = color.green, linewidth=2, title='9 EMA', display=display.none)
plot(ema(close, 18), color = color.red, linewidth=2, title='18 EMA', display=display.none)
```

Comment: Can you share your full code? You must have something wrong. I tested the code myself before posting it.